# 3 Table JOIN - With two unique Identifiers Pulling different data from the third

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables containing dyamic data, both reference a third static table for a description. Imagine this scenario:

```
Cake Table
Sponge Table
Description Table
```

A Sponge is a type of Cake. Each instance of a sponge belongs to an instance of a Cake. Basically, a Sponge has a Cake ID associated with it.

A Cake has a base description that fits the style of the cake. This is a simple numbered index. ie. Cake description might be 25, which in turn equals to "Soft, yet Squeezable", in the Description Table.

Cake Table Rows have an index of their Description. Likewise, a Sponge also has an index of it's description - even if it is the same as the description as the cake.

A sponge belongs to a Cake with Description ID 25 - the Cake is "Soft, yet Squeezable"; but the Sponge also has it's own description index 10 - "Almondy with a less of a bite!".

My question is, how do I pull both descriptions from the third table? It's probably quite simple but I've been working on this for ages trying to come out with a query that works

So far:

```
 SELECT 
    cakes.*,
    sponges.*, 
    descriptions.description as cake_description,
    descriptions.description as sponge_description
         from sponges
             join cakes on cake_id = sponge_id
         join descriptions on cake_desc_id = description_id
```

The above duplicates the Sponge Description in both description fields. Basically, I want to be able to pull Cake Description, and Sponge Description - at the same time.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please provide your TAble structures for Cake,Sponge and Description.For better analysing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A self join from descriptions should get you what you need.  If there are records that have one type of description, but not another, you'd need to change it to a left join.

```
SELECT 
  cakes.*,
  sponges.*, 
  cake_description.description as cake_description,
  sponge_description.description as sponge_description
from sponges
join cakes on cake_id = sponge_id
join descriptions cake_description on cake_description.cake_desc_id = description_id
join descriptions sponge_description on sponge_description.cake_desc_id = description_id
```

Comment: Yep, took me a minute to grasp it, but thanks, that makes perfect sense and works a charm!

Comment: Very nice, this option is commonly overlooked!